# How to fix No developer directory found error in Xcode 4.5.1?

Tags: iphone, ios, unit-testing, xcode4.5, linker-errors

Am working in Xcode 4.5.1 with iOS 6.0. Am new to "**Test**" the iOS applications. Whenever I try to "Test" the app it is showing "**Test Succeeded**" but through an error in Debugger area.
The error message is,

```
Error: No developer directory found at /Volumes/RED Zone/Softrware Dump/Xcode Tools/xcode 4.5.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer. Run /usr/bin/xcode-select to update the developer directory path.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Also I tried to update the path using Terminal like below,

```
/usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/CompanyName/xcode 4.5.1/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

It showed below error message:

```
xcode-select: Error: argument missing from -switch option.
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder-path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
```

I dont know how to fix this issue? Anyone please help me on this? Looking forward your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have had problems using paths with spaces in them before, not sure about now, but you could try using a directory that has no spaces and see. Also, Xcode should be in /Applications:
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: @DavidH thank you for your help. I replaced my Xcode app directly under Applications/ so now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the tab key to autocomplete the directory names; that will escape the spaces. The error is occurring because `xcode-select` doesn't recognise the path you're providing as being valid.